# What is the expected iTunes App Store rating for using a user's own music?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval, rating

So in my new music app game I'm creating, I'm allowing the user to pick a song from his own music, then play it in response to a prompt. Assuming the prompts are all **4+** rating, what would the appropriate rating be for the app once I submit it? Do I call it **4+** since that's what the prompts are? Or **17+** because the user's music *might* be that extreme? Some of my prompts aren't so PG anyway, so it might be a bit of a moot point, but I'm just wondering the most extreme rating an app would take based on the contents of a music library, a sort of precedent. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot predict the contents of a user's music library, so I would go for 4+. If you are really concerned, consider ringing Apple's Developer Support and running it past them before submission.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That was my plan, I just wanted to see if there's any type of precedent.